# проблемы при установке android studio. android sdk отсутствует

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk

Всем привет. Я уже себе мозг сломал при попытке поставить Android Studio. В частности проблема в неком "Android SDK", которого у меня нету, или еще что-то в таком духе. Перед созданием этой темы офк я погуглил и пытался сам решить проблему, но...

---

[image]

Окей, проблемы начинаются от сюда. В руководствах тут всегда три пункта, а у меня всего два.

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Слева у меня открыт youtube руководство, ну а справа мой установщик. Как видите... Причем до этого там было три пункта, вот где зеленые линии, и на против всех было указано "installed". Я просто уже по десять раз все удалял и переустанавливал в надежде.

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Были советы, что мол ерунда, из софта ты все это можешь поставить потом. Как видите не могу. Разделы "SDK Tools" и "SDK Update Sites" неактивны. В "Android SDK Location" бесполезно указывать куда-либо путь, т.к. у меня нету этих файлов. Они ни в каких AppData или еще где-либо не создаются.

---

Ну и общая информация:

1. Win7 x64, относительно новая т.е. пару месяцев назад я её переустановил.
2. Я новичок, и никогда не имел дел с попытками чёт там поделать на mobile, поэтому никакие android studio у меня не могут быть установлены. А даже если я их когда-то очень давно случайно и ставил... стоп, так винда же новая! В этом и дело. Не ставил я.
3. Из софта, ну хз, Visual Studio, Brackets, может что-то еще по WebDev. Причем всё поудалял на всякий случай.
4. Всякие JAVA SE установил, переменные прописал, итд. Всё как в руководствах.
5. Естественно, я постарался отыскать все следы любых Android'oв на компьютере, и выпилить их. Все папки, всякие там .android, итд. Все что нашел. Там же даже в реестре пытался искать упоминания и сносить их тоже. Нету у меня этого на компе.
6. Android Studio скачан с официального сайта.

Как-то так. Надеюсь не упустил ничего важного и сильно не туплю тут :)

Comment: http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/9-urok-2-ustanovka-i-nastrojka-sredy-razrabotki.html почитате здесь

Comment: и что, по этому пути users/kakutokarate/appdata/local/android/sdk ничего нет?

Comment: @pavlofff Нет, ничего не было. Проблема решилась установкой более ранней версии Android Studio 2.3.3.

Comment: @Pantera Спасибо, установка более ранней версии Android 2.3.3 помогла.

Comment: У меня была такая же проблема. Попробуй отдельно установить с официального сайта.

Comment: А вы нашли ответ?у меня тоже такая ошибка не могу найти ответ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В моем случае установка более ранней версии Android Studio 2.3.3 помогла.

http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/9-urok-2-ustanovka-i-nastrojka-sredy-razrabotki.html (ссылка которую дал пользователь в комментариях выше, может кому-то поможет)

https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать включить VPN запустить прогу. Он не найдет sdk, жмяк дальше, предложит доустановить пакет, а дальше понятно.