# Android Studio не предлагает установить android sdk

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk

Скачал с оф сайта Android Studio EXEшник, но при установке нет варианта для Android sdk.JDK Установил в дефолтную папаку

Comment: А в чём вопрос) ? P.s можно и так поставить jdk и указать для студии путь к jdk

Comment: Указать где?(Сорян за тупость, я впервые с Android'ом дело имею)

Comment: Правый верхний угол File->Project structure -> SDK location

Comment: Путь к jdk указал, но после нажатия кнопки "ok" снова выдаёт старый путь:C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre
И всё же ошибка остаётся, Android skd location shuld not contain white space, в строке с указанием androisd sdk вообще ничего нет.

Comment: Видимо у вас новый путь содержит пробелы (так в ошибке сказано), попробуйте переименовать папку "Android Studio" d "Android_Studio"

Comment: Создал папку sdk, захожу в sdk Maneger, меню путь D:\Program files(x86)\Android SDK(Понятия не имею почему изначально стоит он, т.к. если зайти в D:\Program files(x86) то папки Android SDK там не будет) пытаюсь изменить на C:\Program Files\Android\sdk выдаёт ту же ошибку:" SDK shuold not contain white space, as this can cause problems with NDK tools. Нажимаю "ok" но прошлое место сохраняется, так же при установке Android API выдаёт ошибку:"Your Android SDK is missing out of date corrupted.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/764029/177345

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогло :)